# Trim string of words based on character count

Tags: php, strings, wordpress

I needed a simple way to trim a string of words based on a max character count. I also needed to cut in-between words. Using WordPress, here is what I came up with, but I feel like it could be more efficient.

```
function count_words($content) {
    $partsArray = explode(' ', $content);
    return sizeof($partsArray);
}

function custom_length_excerpt_max_char($content, $max_chars_limit) {
    $count = 0;
    $word_limit;
    while (strlen($content) > $max_chars_limit) {
        $word_limit = count_words($content);
        $word_limit -= 1;
        $content = wp_trim_words($content, $word_limit, '');
        $count++;
        if ($count > 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        $content .= '&#8230;';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

I was originally using `str_word_count` to count the words but it was choking on HTML-encoded characters in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited this code and came up with a better solution than my first based on the answer by janos and by an answer on stackoverflow.com https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161830/117068

This removes multiple iterations and utilizes better built core functions of php.

```
    function custom_length_excerpt_max_char($content, $max_chars_limit) {
        $content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
        $break = '##splitme##';

        if ( strlen($content) > $max_chars_limit ) {
            $content = wordwrap($content, ($max_chars_limit - 3), $break);
            $content = explode($break, $content);
            $content = array_shift($content) . '&#8230;';
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

The `($max_chars_limit - 3)` compensates for the ellipses added on to the end of the trimmed content.

### Update

Because this is specific to wordpress, the content to be trimmed could have HTML tags in it. I realized that before trimming the content, all tags need to be removed first to prevent unclosed tag sets. Wordpress provides `wp_strip_all_tags` to do just that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's extremely inefficient, because in every iteration you count the number of words twice: once in `count_words`, and then `wp_trim_words` internally has to count the words again.

Another problem is that the method won't work for content that is many words larger than the target limit length. For example with a content of 4000 chars and a limit of 100, due to the `if ($count > 10) break` check in the middle, the method will basically cut off the last 10 words and return a still very large content. Not sure if that was part of your plan.

I don't really know PHP. But here's a naive implementation that should be more efficient and work with long content too:

```
function is_letter($char) {
    return ctype_alpha($char) || in_array($char, ['-']);
}

function custom_length_excerpt_max_char($content, $max_chars_limit) {
    if (strlen($content) < $max_chars_limit) {
        return $content;
    }
    $cut_at = $max_chars_limit;
    for (; $cut_at >= 0 && is_letter($content{$cut_at}); --$cut_at);
    return substr($content, 0, $cut_at);
}

function test_custom_length_excerpt_max_char() {
    $sample = 'some sample-text some sample-text';
    for ($i = 5; $i < strlen($sample) + 10; ++$i) {
        echo custom_length_excerpt_max_char($sample, $i)."\n";
    }
}
```

Here's the logic behind the main function:

- If the content is shorter than the limit, return it
- Iterate backward from the target limit position, until you find something that's NOT a letter, and break the content there.

If you run the test function, the output is something like:

```
...
some
some
some sample-text
some sample-text
some sample-text
some sample-text
some sample-text
some sample-text some
some sample-text some
some sample-text some
...
```